# How to Check All Checkboxes using JavaScript in a table row emitted by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I am new to PHP. I want to create a script to check all checkboxes in a row, but I am stuck.

**PROBLEM**

Code is not working with loop.

Here is my output

[image]

When I check the checkbox under the Opinion column I want to automatically check all checkboxes in the same row.

Here is my code

To render data and checkboxes for each row I use a server-side PHP loop

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>      
$('.allcb').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
 <?php
        for ($i=0; $i<count($opinion); $i++) {
    //if ($opinion[$i] == "")continue;
        ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <!-- <input type="text" name="opinion[]" value="<?php //echo $opinion[$i]?>" size="28" readonly="readonly" />-->

      <input type="checkbox" name="opinion[]" class="allcb" data-child="chk" value="<?php echo $opinion[$i]?>" />
      <?php echo $opinion[$i]?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $action[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $action[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="long_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $long_term[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $long_term[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p_long_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo !empty($p_long_term[$i])?$p_long_term[$i]:'';?>" />
      <?php echo !empty($p_long_term[$i])?$p_long_term[$i]: '';?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="short_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $short_term[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $short_term[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p_short_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo !empty($p_short_term[$i])?$p_short_term[$i]:'';?>" />
      <?php echo !empty($p_short_term[$i])?$p_short_term[$i]: '';?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="outlook[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $outlook[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $outlook[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rating_type[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
        }
?>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);` select all checkbox with class chk in same row

Comment: Are the rows dynamically added?

Comment: @fuyushimoya i used loop to print my data in row

Comment: Then check the console, is it complain that `$` is undefined or something? or this `<script>` appears at `head`? It'd be better to wrap that function in a `domready` to ensure the target elements exist.

Comment: @fuyushimoya Everything is running fine, I have just issue in Chkboxes

Comment: I don't see any issue with your codes. It's working fine for me! Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/fhphqsLL/1/). In the fiddle you can uncomment your selector and check but I suggest to use `$(this).parents('tr').find('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);` instead of multiple `parent()`. See if my selector resolve your issue. Let me know!

Comment: Why don't you put your code (HTML & javascript) on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) ? So we may help you locating where the problem is. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be if you add some identifier to you `TR`s so the `checkbox` "knows" which checkboxes are in the same row.

It would also be possible by checking the parent nodes but this may be a bit unstable (think about restructure the table for example).

```js
function toggleRowCbs(cb) {
  var cbs = document.getElementById(cb.dataset.rowid).querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
  [].forEach.call(cbs, function(x) {
    x.checked = cb.checked;
  });
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 2pt 4pt;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Optionion</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th colspan="4">Ratings</th>
    <th>Outlook</th>
    <th>Rating Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="2">Long Term</th>
    <th colspan="2">Short Term</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Current</th>
    <th>Previous</th>
    <th>Current</th>
    <th>Previous</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowid="row1" onchange="toggleRowCbs(this)" />Foobar
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />Maintain
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />A+
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />A+
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />A1
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />A1
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />Stable
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />Entity
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowid="row2" onchange="toggleRowCbs(this)" />Foobar #2
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />Maintain
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />A+
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />A+
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />A1
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />A1
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />Stable
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />Entity
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So your PHP Code would look like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<count($opinion); $i++) { ?>
      <tr id="row<?php echo $i ?>">
        <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-rowid="row<?php echo $i ?>" onchange="toggleRowCbs(this)" name="opinion[]" class="allcb" data-child="chk" value="<?php echo $opinion[$i]?>" />
      <?php echo $opinion[$i]?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $action[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $action[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="long_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $long_term[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $long_term[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p_long_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo !empty($p_long_term[$i])?$p_long_term[$i]:'';?>" />
      <?php echo !empty($p_long_term[$i])?$p_long_term[$i]: '';?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="short_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $short_term[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $short_term[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p_short_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo !empty($p_short_term[$i])?$p_short_term[$i]:'';?>" />
      <?php echo !empty($p_short_term[$i])?$p_short_term[$i]: '';?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="outlook[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $outlook[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $outlook[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rating_type[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Because this is a vanilla JavaScript solution which uses `querySelectorAll`, `dataset` and `Array.prototype.forEach` this may be not running on all browsers you want.

Comment: this works for me, but OP tagged `jQuery` so why not just do the safe and browser agnostic thing and use it?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary because i wanted to provide a different (vanilla JS) solution.

Comment: @Werner if you see my code i use loop to print my check boxes. Its not working for me

Comment: @Werner Thank You So much. you made my life

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.allcb').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="opinion[]" class="allcb" data-child="chk" value="<?php echo $opinion[$i]?>" />
      <?php echo $opinion[$i]?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $action[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $action[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="long_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $long_term[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $long_term[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p_long_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo !empty($p_long_term[$i])?$p_long_term[$i]:'';?>" />
      <?php echo !empty($p_long_term[$i])?$p_long_term[$i]: '';?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="short_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $short_term[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $short_term[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="p_short_term[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo !empty($p_short_term[$i])?$p_short_term[$i]:'';?>" />
      <?php echo !empty($p_short_term[$i])?$p_short_term[$i]: '';?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="outlook[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $outlook[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $outlook[$i] ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rating_type[]" class="chk" value="<?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?>" />
      <?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Updated with `table` and `tr` tags and jQuery selector also.

Answer (score 1):

```
Simple use this : 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.allcb').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);

  });
});
```

Comment: I have edited the code , refer that, you were missing document ready so the checkbox click event is not bind and also too many parent are useless.

Comment: Its Not Working Yet (

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
 $('.allcb').on('click', function(){  
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);  
 });
```

Or

```
 $('.allcb').on('click', function(){  
      $(this).parents('tr').find('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);  
 });
```

this is just Pekka answer with 1 line more.

Comment: +1 Sunny must be doing it wrong, because this works for me and I use a solution like this all the time in enterprise web apps. (or did, until I started using `AngularJS`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a kind of reference on the other check boxes to the main check box you are checking. Then, when clicking on the main check box, you can control the others. Like this:

Javascript:

```
    $('.allcb').on('click', function(){
        var index = $(this).data('index');

        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $('.childChk' + index).prop('checked', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.childChk' + index).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <?php
            for ($i=0; $i<count($opinion); $i++) {
        //if ($opinion[$i] == "")continue;
            ?>
              <tr>
                <td>
                 <!-- <input type="text" name="opinion[]" value="<?php //echo $opinion[$i]?>" size="28" readonly="readonly" />-->

          <input type="checkbox" name="opinion[]" class="allcb" data-child="chk" data-index="<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo $opinion[$i]?>" />
          <?php echo $opinion[$i]?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="action[]" class="chk chkChild<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo $action[$i] ?>" />
          <?php echo $action[$i] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="long_term[]" class="chk chkChild<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo $long_term[$i] ?>" />
          <?php echo $long_term[$i] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="p_long_term[]" class="chk chkChild<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo !empty($p_long_term[$i])?$p_long_term[$i]:'';?>" />
          <?php echo !empty($p_long_term[$i])?$p_long_term[$i]: '';?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="short_term[]" class="chk chkChild<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo $short_term[$i] ?>" />
          <?php echo $short_term[$i] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="p_short_term[]" class="chk chkChild<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo !empty($p_short_term[$i])?$p_short_term[$i]:'';?>" />
          <?php echo !empty($p_short_term[$i])?$p_short_term[$i]: '';?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="outlook[]" class="chk chkChild<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo $outlook[$i] ?>" />
          <?php echo $outlook[$i] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="rating_type[]" class="chk chkChild<?=$i?>" value="<?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?>" />
          <?php echo $rating_type[$i] ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php
            }
    ?>
```

Note that I added the $i counter to your child check boxes class. This won't change the behavior of any DOM element.

EDIT:

You may NOT call the jQuery library inside the loop. The jQuery library MUST be called just one time. If you call several times, all the solutions presented here will not work.

Comment: Did you removed the $(document).ready statement? I put here only for reference, you should not use in your code. Just take the function implementation and the changes in the HTML code. I edited to remove the document.ready.

Comment: I Copy your code and paste as it is after removing `$(document).ready` but it still not working

Comment: I've edited now the HTML part. Try to copy it and check if it works now. You must call the jQuery library just one time in your code, or nothing will work.

Comment: What if you print the index var? Tell me what you get when doing alert(index) inside javascript code, please. Let's debug it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all the checkBoxes using javascript,

You can give all the checkbox a class,

and then

`var a = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClassName");
for(var key in a) {
   a[key].checked = true;
}`

or

if you want to use jQuery ,

```
$(".yourClassName").attr("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution plays nice with dynamic elements, and uses `className` to identity the row (`.option-row`) instead of relying on `tagName` so that you're not committed to using specific elements to display the data.

Make sure that you include a reference to `jquery.js` before you call the `$` function (as in the example below).

```js
// check or uncheck all boxes with class 'chk' when 'allcb' is clicked
$(document).on('click', '.allcb', function() {
  $('.chk',$(this).closest('.option-row')).prop('checked', this.checked);
});

// simulate PHP; render some rows for demo
var html = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  html.push('<tr class="option-row"><td><input type="checkbox" class="allcb cb"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="chk"/></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="chk"/></td></tr>');
}
$("tbody").html(html.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Opinion</th>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```